# Angular4 jQuery textcomplete issue with HTMLContentEditable Adapter

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Angular 4 with typescript I have successfully integrate jQuery textcomplete in my project and I am able to test with development environment but issue with production environment in adapter at line `adapter: $.fn.textcomplete.HTMLContentEditable,` Here code is at https://github.com/Pyush/MentionHash

it's work fine with ng serve but when I am build with ng build --prod its give me error

```
 Property 'HTMLContentEditable' does not exist on type '(options?: any, callback?: any) => any'.
Property 'HTMLContentEditable' does not exist on type '(options?: any, callback?: any) => any'.
```

**Note :** HTMLContentEditable available in textcomplete jQuery

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this a purely vanilla `ng new` template?

Comment: Indeed looks like you've forgotten to commit your changes to the repository you are linking to

Comment: @DNorthrup its pure new template you can check on github

Comment: @PiyushPatel You're asking us to review your code, but your git isn't updated. I can build a change-less Ng-Cli output for both prod, and dev without an error.

Comment: Please check I commit code sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

I just did typecast Object any to function it's work with production environment.

```
adapter: (<any>$.fn.textcomplete).HTMLContentEditable
```

Thanks